# Progress bar element breaking Chrome rendering (unless Dev Tools open)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, progress

**UPDATED TO ADD FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/wvUqy/6/**

I have a page_action in Chrome that parses the response from an XHR to make a menu of video clips for download. There is a `<span class="status">` for each clip that defaults to blank, shows "Pending" when queued, and changes to either "INTERRUPTED" (in red) or "Complete" depending on how the download stops. These behaviors, and updating `<span class="status">` with percentage of download complete as it progressed all work fine.

I tried to swap out displaying the percentage string for a `<progress>` bar instead, but as soon as I introduce that element into the document, I start getting rendering problems **ONLY WHEN** I'm not using Chrome Dev Tools.

Here's a 2min video of the odd behavior in action:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M50F5ly93MM

The fiddle link at the top will output to console as it periodically (every 5s) changes display property for the `<span>` and `<progress>` elements, but they never appear. If you comment out the line `subDiv.appendChild('progressBar')` and change nothing else, the behavior of the `<span class="Status">` is magically fixed.

Everything works as expected when no `<progress>` elements are in the document; it works as expected if the `setInterval` var is created within a button's `onclick` function; it works as expected if you "Inspect Element" the result pane in Dev Tools.

In all cases, it works as expected in Firefox, but I'm trying to build a Chrome extension specifically.

Comment: I've seen screenshots with hand-draw circles/arrows/text, jsfiddles, links to live sites but a YT video demo is the first time. +1 GL

Comment: I'll try to replicate behavior in a fiddle tomorrow, but wanted to get this out there with what I had handy in case it's a known issue.

Comment: Yes, you've put quite some effort making a detailed video description, did you test it in other browsers to check the behavior? I'm also too tired to debug it atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably running into a manifestation of https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84242 - a bisection gave me http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/83065 which dealt with a major rewrite of the `<progress>` element implementation. I will link that bug to this question - perhaps the former will get some more attention.

Comment: Thank you for the tip - I'll investigate this bug further.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated a progress bar bug recently. I filed the bug to webkit, you may find it relevant: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100507 .

Answer (score 0):

So there is apparently a hacky way to get around this: http://jsfiddle.net/wvUqy/9/

For reasons I don't quite understand, making a trivial update to the containing `<div>` (e.g. `ChildContainer.style.display = ChildContainer.style.display;`) when updating the `<progress>` and `<span>` element(s) will correct the rendering behavior.

I've implemented this in my page_action script and it works fine. Would be nice if this bug were resolved in Chrome, but this is a fine interim solution.